# Commitlint - Types for '.commitlintrc.js'

Tags: javascript, typescript, commitlint

In the `.commitlintrc.js` file, I wanted to type the exported configuration option, so that my IDE could suggest possible options.

```js
/** @type {import('@commitlint/types').UserConfig} */
module.exports = {
  extends: ["@commitlint/config-conventional"],
}
```

But it doesn't work for some reason (no suggestions) and I don't know what I'm missing here.

[image]

`index.d.ts` is located in `node_modules/@commitlint/types/lib/index.d.ts`
[image]

In `@commitlint/types`, the `UserConfig` is exported like this (https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/blob/v17.7.1/%40commitlint/types/src/load.ts#L23):

```js
export interface UserConfig {
    extends?: string | string[];
    // other options...
}
```

---

I've used the same approach for `prettier` & `stylelint` config and in that case I get suggestions in my IDE:

```js
/** @type {import('stylelint').Config} */
module.exports = {
  extends: [....]
}
```

```js
/** @type {import('prettier').Config} */
module.exports = {
  printWidth: 100,
  singleQuote: true,
  jsxSingleQuote: true
};
```

---

As described in the [docs](https://commitlint.js.org/#/reference-configuration?id=typescript), I can make a `ts` file with the following content:

```js
import type {UserConfig} from '@commitlint/types';

const Configuration: UserConfig = {
  extends: ["@commitlint/config-conventional"],
};

module.exports = Configuration;
```

The above approach works; however, I don't understand what is missing in the initial config.

Comment: Have you tried `module.exports = /* @type Foo */( {extends:[]} )` (with () brackets)

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried making it a TS file with `import type {Foo} from 'bar'; const foo: Foo = bar; export = foo` ? Do types work at all?

Comment: Because "cannot find declaration" looks like missing d.ts

Comment: @Dimava, I've updated the question with the relevant information.

Comment: Have you tried adding `// @ts-check` comment on top of file?

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/Shinigami92/eslint-define-config requires it in .eslintrc.cjs

Comment: yes, still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and was able to make it work with one indirection

```js
/** @type {import('@commitlint/types').UserConfig} */
const config = {
  extends: []
};

module.exports = config;
```